# In Java Concurrency In Practice by Brian Goetz, why not simply use computeIfAbsent

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

Java Concurrency In Practice by Brian Goetz provides an implementation of Memoizer on pg 108: [In Java Concurrency In Practice by Brian Goetz, why is the Memoizer class not annotated with @ThreadSafe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528382/in-java-concurrency-in-practice-by-brian-goetz-why-is-the-memoizer-class-not-an)

Instead of this (perhaps over elaborate implementation) what potential downside does the below implementation have?

```
public class ConcurrentMemoizer<A, V> implements Computable<A, V> {

    private final ConcurrentMap<A, V> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private final Computable<A, V> c;

    public ConcurrentMemoizer(Computable<A, V> c) {
        this.c = c;
    }


    @Override
    public V compute(A arg) {
        return cache.computeIfAbsent(arg, a -> c.compute(a);
    }

}
```

Comment: the *linked* ¹  question is from 2010, just before Java 7 was released - Java did not have Lambdas back that time, or even before, when the book was written? (`computeIfAbsent` was added in Java 8, released 2014) || **¹** not really linked!

Comment: The advantage is that it implements a specific interface that is not implemented by (Concurrent)(Hash)Map.

Comment: Your code has a syntax error (missing `)`) but besides that would work, but is pointless. Replace `Computable<A, V>` with `Function<A, V>` (mind that this also is an interface that didn’t exist back then), then you can pass the “computable” directly to `computeIfAbsent`, which makes the entire `ConcurrentMemoizer` obsolete, as you can use a `ConcurrentHashMap` in the first place.

Comment: From the [javadoc of `ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function)): _"Some attempted update operations on this map by other threads may be blocked while computation is in progress, so the computation should be short and simple."_, so if `c.compute(a)` is something that takes a while, it might not be a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In Java Concurrency In Practice by Brian Goetz, why not simply use `computeIfAbsent`.

If you are asking why the book didn't use it, one answer is that `ConcurrentHashMap` didn't have `computeIfAbsent` when the book was published.

If you are asking why *you* shouldn't use it, the reason is in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function)) caveat that @Mark Rotteveel pointed out:

> *"Some attempted update operations on this map by other threads may be blocked while computation is in progress, so the computation should be short and simple."*

Explanation: If you look at the source code of `computeIfAbsent(key, function)` in a typical `ConcurrentHashMap` implementation, you will see that it holds a lock on the submap in which the `key` lives.  Other threads that access other keys in the same submap will be blocked.  This is problematic if the call to `function` takes a long time.  The book talks about this problem too.

Goetz's final version on page 108 deals with this using a `FutureTask` and `putIfAbsent`.  The blocking time is minimal except when the another thread trying to get the value that you are currently computing.

---

> *"... why is the `Memoizer` class not annotated with `@ThreadSafe`?"*

I'd say that is just an oversight.  There are other examples in the book where thread-safe classes haven't been annotated with `@ThreadSafe`.  (Note that these annotations are only advisory.  They don't *make* the code thread-safe.)

Comment: In case of OpenJDK, on which most implementations are built, the locking only affects the particular key. Further, this locking does not affect every access, but “*attempted update operations*”, as the documentation says. E.g. a fundamental principle of `ConcurrentHashMap` is that a simple `get(…)` never blocks.